# Implement Thread in Turbo C++

Tags: dos, turbo-c++

How to Implement Thread in Turbo C++?

Answer (score 1):

Depends on which version of Turbo C++.  DOS has no threads, and versions up Turbo C++ 3.0 [were strictly for DOS](https://secure.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/wiki/Turbo_C%2B%2B). Turbo C++ versions 3.0 and up have support for Windows development, but only the Win16 API, so the program won't work on 64-bit versions of Windows.

If you really want to create a "thread" in DOS, you can use a [TSR](http://www.digitalmars.com/rtl/tsr.html) routine in DOS, though those work pretty bad under Windows.

(Higher versions of Borland C++ support modern versions of Windows.)